# Windows upload from command line gives Access Denied

Tags: arduino-uno, uploading, windows, command-line

saw somewhere that in order to upload a hex file to an arduino you can look at the Arduino IDE - see the command it runs, then replace the hex file with your file.
this is the command I see in the output window:

`C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.42.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.42.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM5 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\yossi\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_696128/sketch_aug21a.ino.hex:i`

I try running this from command (as admin):

```
cd "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.42.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr\bin"
avrdude -CC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.42.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM5 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\foosMaster\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_696128/sketch_aug21a.ino.hex:i
```

gives me `Access is denied.`
in fact, just running `avrdude` gives the same error, so really - this has nothing to do with the COM port (which works fine from the IDE)
I tried closing the IDE and running again, tried rebooting - the same.

*** edit 1 ****

I actually ran this:

```
cd "C:\PROGRA~1\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.42.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr\bin"
avrdude -CC:\PROGRA~1\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.42.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM5 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\foosMaster\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_696128/sketch_aug21a.ino.hex:i
```

since I didn't want to mess with wrapping the params - but I don't really think it matters - as the problem is running avrdude without any parameter still gives me the same error: `Access is denied.`

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are running the Windows App Store version of the IDE.

Windows doesn't like you messing with the insides of App Store programs (I think it scares it...).

Install the *real* version of the IDE from the Arduino.cc website and it will work.